# How to round an NSDecimalNumber in swift?

Tags: xcode, swift, nsdecimalnumber

I can't find any resources on this, and I've been trying all sorts of stuff, but nothing works.

According to Apple's documentation, you round an NSDecimalNumber like this:

```
NSDecimalNumber.decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehavior(<#behavior: NSDecimalNumberBehaviors?#>)
```

It takes in an NSDecimalNumberBehavior, which I'm unsure how to manipulate since it (1) cannot be initiated into a variable and have it's properties changed, and (2) the roundingMode() method according to the documentation doesn't take any parameters, but Xcode fills in a parameter space for "self".

I'm totally lost on this. Back to the basic question; How can I round an NSDecimalNumber in swift?

Thanks in advance

Comment: NSDecimalNumber.decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehavior: is not a class method. This means that you can call on a decimal number instance, to obtain its rounded value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can do it like that

```
let x = 5
let y = 2
let total = x.decimalNumberByDividingBy(y).decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehavior( NSDecimalNumberHandler(roundingMode: NSRoundingMode.RoundUp, scale: 0, raiseOnExactness: false, raiseOnOverflow: false, raiseOnUnderflow: false, raiseOnDivideByZero: false))
```

Comment: Like string manipulation and other things in Swift, is anyone else perturbed by how much code is required to simply do this?

Comment: This is obviously not the correct answer. Why is this the accepted answer? The question was asking about NSDecimalNumber, not about dividing Ints.

Answer (score 9):

`NSDecimalNumberBehaviors` is a *protocol* and thus cannot be instantiated. You need an object of a *class* conforming to the protocol. Apple provides the class `NSDecimalNumberHandler` for this purpose, e.g.:

```
let handler = NSDecimalNumberHandler(roundingMode: NSRoundingMode.RoundBankers, scale: 0, raiseOnExactness: false, raiseOnOverflow: false, raiseOnUnderflow: false, raiseOnDivideByZero: false)
let rounded = dec.decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehavior(handler)
```

The `scale` argument is the number of decimals you want, i.e., `0` rounds to an integer.

Comment: Using the defaultDecimalNumberHandler doesn't seem to make any rounding. Can you provide an example?

Comment: @Naldhelaan My bad regarding the default handler, see example for how to construct your own.

Answer (score 2):

```
// get a decimal num from a string

let num = NSDecimalNumber.init(string: numStr)

// create an NSDecimalNumberHandler instance 

let behaviour = NSDecimalNumberHandler(roundingMode:.RoundUp, 
scale: 1, raiseOnExactness: false, 
raiseOnOverflow: false, raiseOnUnderflow: 
false, raiseOnDivideByZero: false)

// pass the handler to the method decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehaviour.

// This is an instance method on NSDecimalNumber that takes an object that
// conforms to the protocol NSDecimalNumberBehaviors, which NSDecimalNumberHandler does!

let numRounded = num.decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehavior(behaviour)
```