# How to store 1.66 in NSDecimalNumber

Tags: swift, nsdecimalnumber

I know float or double are not good for storing decimal number like money and quantity. I'm trying to use NSDecimalNumber instead. Here is my code in Swift playground.

```
let number:NSDecimalNumber = 1.66
let text:String = String(describing: number)
NSLog(text)
```

The console output is 1.6599999999999995904

How can I store the exact value of the decimal number 1.66 in a variable?

Comment: Check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31070910/2975371

Comment: Thanks @Danieboy. I'm new to swift. Can you provide me sample code that  how to store 1.66 exactly in a variable?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In

```
let number:NSDecimalNumber = 1.66
```

the right-hand side is a floating point number which cannot represent
the value "1.66" exactly. One option is to create the decimal number
from a string:

```
let number = NSDecimalNumber(string: "1.66")
print(number) // 1.66
```

Another option is to use arithmetic:

```
let number = NSDecimalNumber(value: 166).dividing(by: 100)
print(number) // 1.66
```

With Swift 3 you may consider to use the "overlay value type" `Decimal` instead, e.g.

```
let num = Decimal(166)/Decimal(100)
print(num) // 1.66
```

Yet another option:

```
let num = Decimal(sign: .plus, exponent: -2, significand: 166)
print(num) // 1.66
```

**Addendum:**

Related discussions in the Swift forum:

- [Exact NSDecimalNumber via literal](https://forums.swift.org/t/exact-nsdecimalnumber-via-literal/12834)
- [ExpressibleByFractionLiteral](https://forums.swift.org/t/expressiblebyfractionliteral/8161)

Related bug reports:

- [SR-3317
  Literal protocol for decimal literals should support precise decimal accuracy](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3317), closed as a duplicate of
- [SR-920
  Re-design builtin compiler protocols for literal convertible types](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-920).