# NSDecimalNumber usage for precision with currency in Swift

Tags: swift, currency, nsdecimalnumber

I've read a lot that `NSDecimalNumber` is the best format to use when using currency.

However, I'm still getting floating point issues.

For example.

```
let a: NSDecimalNumber = 0.07 //0.07000000000000003
let b: NSDecimalNumber = 7.dividing(by: 100) //0.06999999999999999
```

I know I could use `Decimal` and b would be what I'm expecting:

```
let b: Decimal = 7 / 100 //0.07
```

I'm using Core Data in my app. So I'm stuck with `NSDecimalNumber`. Unless I want convert a lot of `NSDecimalNumbers` to `Decimals`.

Can someone help me get 0.07?

Comment: You should rather use a `NumberFormatter` when displaying currency data to the user.

Comment: Just use NumberFormatter to display your number. Btw 0.06999999999999999 and 0.07 it is practically the same number. Btw I would use Decimal and cast it to NSDecimalNumber when needed

Comment: Thanks @DávidPásztor. Helped me realise I'm going about this the wrong way.

Comment: The problem is that the `0.07` that you're assigning is itself a `Double`, which is introducing the precision issues before `NSDecimalNumber` comes into play. If you want a lossless representation of `0.07`, you need to use the `NSDecimalNumber` initializer that takes a string `"0.07"`

Comment: "Unless I want convert a lot of `NSDecimalNumbers` to `Decimals`" ... Note, you don't really have to "convert" as it's toll-free bridged for you. So to get the `NSDecimalNumber` rendition, it just requires a simple `as NSDecimalNumber`. But I get your point.

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42781785/how-to-store-1-66-in-nsdecimalnumber

Comment: @MartinR - Sorry, I didn’t see your answer out there (which turns out to be virtually identical to my answer; I swear I didn’t see yours!). Feel free to mark this as dupe and I can delete my answer here, if you’d like.

Comment: @Rob: There is no need to apologize or to explain yourself – I would never have thought anything else.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you’re effectively doing floating point math (with the problems it has faithfully capturing fractional decimal values in a `Double`) and creating a `Decimal` (or `NSDecimalNumber`) from the `Double` value that already has introduced this discrepancy. Instead, you want to create your `Decimal` values before doing your division (or before having a fractional `Double` value, even if a literal).

So, the following is equivalent to your example, whereby it is building a `Double` representation (with the limitations that entails) of `0.07`, and you end up with a value that is not exactly `0.07`:

```
let value = Decimal(7.0 / 100.0)                                // or NSDecimalNumber(value: 7.0 / 100.0)
```

Whereas this does not suffer this problem because we are dividing a decimal `7` by a decimal `100`:

```
let value = Decimal(7) / Decimal(100)                           // or NSDecimalNumber(value: 7).dividing(by: 100)
```

Or, other ways to create `0.07` value but avoiding `Double` in the process include using strings:

```
let value = Decimal(string: "0.07")                             // or NSDecimalNumber(string: "0.07")
```

Or specifying the mantissa/significant and exponent:

```
let value = Decimal(sign: .plus, exponent: -2, significand: 7)  // or NSDecimalNumber(mantissa: 7, exponent: -2, isNegative: false)
```

Bottom line, avoid `Double` representations entirely when using `Decimal` (or `NSDecimalNumber`), and you won't suffer the problem you described.

Comment: Really well put. Thanks a lot! This has really helped me out.

Comment: ```Decimal(7)``` will work for a simple digit like 7 but a more accurate approach is to use ```NSNumber(floatLiteral: 7).decimalValue```. I use ```Decimal``` for financial transactions and there are several cases where ```Decimal(7)``` like approach doesn't result in accurate results with currencies. Though that difference is minute, but it adds up in financial transactions.

Comment: I’d suggest one be careful with `NSNumber(floatLiteral: x).decimalValue` pattern, too, because that takes `x`, with any concomitant floating point issues, and simply captures those issues. I’d still advise, as a general rule, when using non-integer values, using one of the patterns above.