# Is Decimal number suitable data type for precise money conversion operation?

Tags: swift, decimal, precision, number-formatting, nsnumberformatter

I have an issue where I need to have result with different precisions maximum one is up to 18 digits after coma.

Because this operation contains money I decided to use `Decimal` type. So I have questions.

- Is `Decimal` data type suitable to represent values up to 18
  digits after coma?
- Will I have different behavior on older phones    such as iPhone 5
  with that data type?
- Are any corner cases when usage of the `Decimal` and `NumberFormatter()` with `maximumFractionDigits` = 18 ? (Wrong rounding .. etc)

This is my case with example usage:

I have price for coin in USD:

```
let pricePerCoin: Decimal = 950.83
```

Than I have amount in USD that I will use to buy coins.

```
let amountInUSD: Decimal = 10000
```

I use formatter to be able to convert `Decimal` number to string with respect of the `maximumFractionDigits`.

```
let fractionDigits = 18

let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
formatter.groupingSeparator = ""
formatter.isLenient = true
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = fractionDigits
```

Result

```
let result = formatter.string(for: amountInUSD/pricePerCoin) // 10.517127141550011933
```

Comment: The exact limitations are documented here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdecimalnumber.

Comment: Note that you lose precision in `let pricePerCoin: Decimal = 950.83`, compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/42782140/1187415 (and write `let pricePerCoin = Decimal(95083)/Decimal(100)` instead)

Comment: @MartinR yeah thx for the link. But is the lose of precision (let pricePerCoin = Decimal(95083)/Decimal(100))  is critical in my case?

Comment: How can I judge how critical the precision is in your application? – It makes the result change from 10.517127141550011933 to 10.517127141550014198, and that is closer to the number 10.51712714155001419812164109251916746421547490087607669089 from Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: @MartinR yes you are right thx for help!