# Parsing Decimal from JSON presented as string

Tags: swift, ios13, codable

With Xcode 10.2 and iOS 12.x we were able to extract Decimal from json string. With Xcode 11.1 and iOS 13.1 it is throwing exception

> Expected to decode Double but found a string/data instead.

```
class MyClass : Codable {

     var decimal: Decimal?
 }
```

then trying to parse it

```
let json = "{\"decimal\":\"0.007\"}"
let data = json.data(using: .utf8)
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.nonConformingFloatDecodingStrategy = .convertFromString(positiveInfinity: "s1", negativeInfinity: "s2", nan: "s3")
 do {
   let t = try decoder.decode(MyClass.self, from: data!)
 } catch {
   print(error)
 }
```

If I change json string as

`let json = "{\"decimal\":0.007}"`

It works, but then again we are losing precision. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/55131900/2303865

Comment: Are you receiving a string or a double from the server?

Comment: I'm receiving both, but nowdays the string is the problematic one. Parsing double to decimal works still fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let decimal: Decimal
}
```

---

```
extension Root {
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        decimal = try Decimal(string: container.decode(String.self, forKey: .decimal)) ?? .zero
    }
}
```

---

```
let json = #"{"decimal":"0.007"}"# 
do {
    let root = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: .init(json.utf8))
    print(root)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

This will print

> Root(decimal: 0.007)

Comment: This is getting closer. Now if I have models like this
'
class SomeModel : Codable
{
var title: String
var enabled: Bool
var amount : Root  // used to be Decimal before
etc
}
'
And it's quite common that I need Decimal in several objects that I'm receiving. I have to implement quite a lot of code that used to work automatically

Comment: I think that the easiest would be to treat them as strings.  You can have computed properties to return the decimal value

Comment: Yeps, I actually ended up writing modified version of JSONDecoder which accepts strings as well. This was still best answer for the actual problem so marking this ad solved

Answer (score 8):

You would need to extend KeyedDecodingContainer and add an implementation for Decimal.Type.

```
extension KeyedDecodingContainer {
    func decode(_ type: Decimal.Type, forKey key: K) throws -> Decimal {
        let stringValue = try decode(String.self, forKey: key)
        guard let decimalValue = Decimal(string: stringValue) else {
            let context = DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [key], debugDescription: "The key \(key) couldn't be converted to a Decimal value")
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(type, context)
        }
        return decimalValue
    }
}
```

Here is an example:

```
let json = """
{
  "capAmount": "123.45"
}
"""

struct Status: Decodable {
    let capAmount: Decimal

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case capAmount
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        capAmount = try container.decode(Decimal.self, forKey: .capAmount)
    }
}

// Execute it
if let data = json.data(using: .utf8){
    let status = try JSONDecoder().decode(Status.self, from: data)
    print(status.capAmount)
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it work with optional Decimal?

Comment: @Dmitry https://stackoverflow.com/a/62997953/2303865

Answer (score 3):

I just add the following code.
It supports optional as well.

```swift
extension KeyedDecodingContainer {

    func decode(_ type: Decimal.Type, forKey key: K) throws -> Decimal {
        let stringValue = try decode(String.self, forKey: key)
        guard let decimalValue = Decimal(string: stringValue) else {
            let context = DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [key], debugDescription: "The key \(key) couldn't be converted to a Decimal value")
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(type, context)
        }
        return decimalValue
    }

    func decodeIfPresent(_ type: Decimal.Type, forKey key: K) throws -> Decimal? {
        guard 
            let stringValue = try? decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: key),
            let decimalValue = Decimal(string: stringValue)
        else { return nil }
        return decimalValue
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That decoding strategy has nothing to do with numbers being represented as strings. What you need to do is to implement `init(from:)` and convert from string there

```
class MyClass : Codable {
    var decimal: Double?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case decimal = "test"
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        decimal = Double(try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .decimal)
        //or if Decimal is used:
        //decimal = Decimal(string: try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .decimal)
    }
}
```

Note that I am using Double instead of Decimal here to make it simpler

Answer (score -1):

I believe that a cleaner solution is declare value not like a string but like a value:

```
"test": 0.007
```

having a struct like that:

```
struct Stuff {
     var test: Decimal
}
```

and then:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let stuff = try decoder.decode(Stuff.self, from: json)
```

otherwise you can use this example:

https://forums.swift.org/t/parsing-decimal-values-from-json/6906/3

Comment: I cannot control what backend is sending and this used to work before. Example was just for clarification of problem

Comment: ok, you can try this example: https://forums.swift.org/t/parsing-decimal-values-from-json/6906/3

Comment: In that case I would have to specify keys before hand. I actually would prefer to use variable names as key.

Answer (score -1):

The type should be Double and define also in the parsing as Double. Swift will figure out the rest

```
struct MyClass: Decodable {
        let decimal: Double

        //can be renamed to follow the API name.
        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case decimal
        }
    }
    extension MyClass {
        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

            let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            decimal = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .decimal)

        }
    }
```