# Value should be rounded to nearest tenth or the nearest quarter

Tags: ios, swift, math, swift2

I need to round number to nearest tenth or the nearest quarter.

For example:

If values are from 0.225 to 0.265, they are round to 0.25 and when they are
from 0.265 to 0.350, they are round to 0.30.

So i need to know what is the nearest rounding is for certain number and than round it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easiest way to truncate float to 2 decimal places?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27827742/easiest-way-to-truncate-float-to-2-decimal-places)

Comment: @EricD. unfortunalty this solution do not handle condition for the nearest tenth rounding of quarter rounding.

Comment: First range (0.25-0.025..0.25 + 0.015), second (0.3-0.035..0.3+0.05). What is a law for this rounding?

Comment: It should round value to the nearest tenth or the nearest quarter. For example (x.00-x.05) = x.00 (x.265-x.350) = x.30  (x.730-x.765) = x.75

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `switch` statement.

**Main func:**

```
func differentRounding(value:Double) -> Double {

    var decimalValue = value % 1
    let intValue = value - decimalValue

    switch decimalValue {
    case 0.225..<0.265 :
        decimalValue = 0.25
    case 0.725..<0.765 :
        decimalValue = 0.75
    default :
        decimalValue = ((decimalValue * 10).roundDownTillFive()) / 10
    }

    return decimalValue + intValue
}

differentRounding(1.2434534545) // 1.25
differentRounding(3.225345346) // 2.25
differentRounding(0.2653453645) // 0.3
differentRounding(0.05) // 0
differentRounding(0.04456456) // 0
```

**Rounding down till `5` extension:**

```
extension Double {
    func roundDownTillFive() -> Double {

        var decimalValue = self % 1
        let intValue = self - decimalValue

        switch decimalValue {
        case 0.0...0.5 :
            decimalValue = 0.0
        case 0.5...1.0 :
            decimalValue = 1.0
        default :
            break
        }

        return decimalValue + intValue
    }
}

Double(0.5).roundDownTillFive() // 0
Double(0.50000001).roundDownTillFive() // 1
```

Comment: Thx for the idea but in my case amount of the cases in unlimited and this case is not suitable. But thx for you're idea!

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk how is it unlimited?

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk How are your cases unlimited? There are only a finite number of these ranges between 0 and 1. Note the initial "value %1"

Comment: @RobNapier sorry i just realize the conditions and you are right. Thx for helping.

Comment: Hmmm but this code example should be edited because of (x.00-x.05) = x.00 @RMenke. Try to set 0.05.

Comment: @RMenke yes, maybe "round number to nearest tenth or the nearest quarter" is not really, what Oleg want ...

Comment: @user3441734 yes his ranges are different from standard rounding. But got a pretty simple solution in my last update.

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk take a look at the last update. It's almost elegant now.

Answer (score 1):

```
import Foundation

func specround(d: Double)->Double {
    let d1 = round(d * 10) / 10
    let d2 = round(d * 4 ) / 4

    return abs(d2-d) < abs(d1-d) ? d2 : d1
}

specround(1.2249999) // 1.2
specround(1.225)     // 1.25
specround(1.276)     // 1.3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extension to double to round to the nearest double amount rounding up for any value that is equal to the input divided by 2.

```
extension Double {
    func roundToNearestValue(value: Double) -> Double {
        let remainder = self % value
        let shouldRoundUp = remainder >= value/2 ? true : false
        let multiple = floor(self / value)
        let returnValue = !shouldRoundUp ? value * multiple : value * multiple + value
        return returnValue
    }
}
```